# Is there any possibility to replace Blender 2.80 Keymap with Blender 2.79b keymap?

Tags: shortcut

I searched for 2.80 shortcuts but there's not any at the moment and i
thought if i
could change it to previous blender settings

Comment: Here are some links to current shortcuts on 2.8: https://developer.blender.org/T55162 and https://developer.blender.org/T55194

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to the preferences window and set the keymap to 2.7x

[image]